# React state vs CSS :hover. Dropdown menu used both by desktop users (mouse) and mobile users (touch)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, hover

I have this dropdown menu that will be used both by Desktop/PC users **(with mouse)** and Mobile devices **(with touch)**.

Here is what I've thought of on how to implement it:

**OPTION 1**

Implement it using `:hover` and deal with some possible issues like removing the `:hover` state on mobile after user clicks on a dropdown item.

**OPTION 2**

Implement it using React `const [open,setOpen] = useState(boolean)` and listen for `click` events (will happen mostly on mobile) and for `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave` events (will only happen in PC/Desktop).

Is there a best practice for this situation? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the best practice use a :hover in media query for desktop and click keyDown/keyUp events in react or out for mobile

Comment: Would you detect mobile by screen size or by user agent?

Comment: not sure what you mean user agent i use media quary and use breakpoints you can look up to get sizes that are pc and size thats less is touch based

Comment: Thanks. That's one way of handling it. I do use breakpoints, but keep in mind that screen sizes don't have anything to do with touch/mouse devices. A small screen does not mean you are on a phone/table with touch devices and vice-versa.

Comment: your right it dosnt always mean that but for the few times it dosnt then the code will still work just a bit less user friendly so its fine ps never heard of that other way what is it ?

Comment: ps how long you used stack overflow your like top 0.5 ? just asking you dont need to answer

Comment: This is the regex/test I do to detect touch (or at least to detect that it's actually a mobile device). `/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)`. Is reads the browser user agent and look for those expressions on it.